# How to expand multiple rows in a Mat Table on clicking of a row in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was trying to create a `mat-table` grid which allows expanding multiple rows on clicking of the rows.

Currently what I have allows only 1 row to expanded at once, when I click on the second row the first rows gets collapsed. Is it possible to expand multiple rows at a time without collapsing other?

I tried with [multiple] keywords but that didn't help.

StackBlitz Link for a single row expansion

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to make multiple rows expanded

change the click handler from (tracking single item):

```
(click)="expandedElement = row"
```

to track multiple

```
(click)="toggleRow(row)"
```

TS part using a simple array to add / remove rows to be expanded

```
  toggleRow(row) {
    const index = this.expandedElements.findIndex(x => x.name == row.name);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.expandedElements.push(row);
    } else {
      this.expandedElements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

next change this:

```
[@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
```

to this:

```
[@detailExpand]="isExpanded(row)"
```

TS part

```
  isExpanded(row): string {
    if (
      this.expandedElements.findIndex(x => x.name == row.element.name) !== -1
    ) {
      return 'expanded';
    }
    return 'collapsed';
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows-8xmcpf?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

Comment: Great solution thanks for this answer.
I would only recommend for performance improvement:
instead of the isExpanded function that is calling the function on every mouse move use expandedElements.includes(element.name) in the template.