# Expanding multiple rows in a nested mat table in Angular not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table, angular-material-table

I have created a nested mat-table grid using Angular Material. But currently only 1 row gets expanded at a time. I want to add a feature so that multiple rows can be expanded at a time, without the previous one getting collapsed.

Working Stackblitz link for Nested Table - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table

Tried pushing elements to ExpandedElement Array but that didn't work much -

```js
const index = this.expandedElements.findIndex(x => x.name == row.name);
if (index === -1) {
  this.expandedElements.push(row);
} else {
  this.expandedElements.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to add multiple row expansion in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expand/collapse logic is quite similar as in the answer for [How to expand multiple rows in a Mat Table on clicking of a row in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081657/8017690).

### Concepts (TL;DR)

1. `toggleElement` function to **Add `element` to `expandedElement`**.
2. `isExpanded` function to **Check `element` is existed in `expandedElement`**.
3. Display element (is expanded/collapsed) with `isExpanded`.

---

### SOLUTION

**Previous**

```
<div class="example-element-detail" *ngIf="element.addresses?.data.length" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
  <div class="inner-table mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="expandedElement">
```

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" [class.example-element-row]="element.addresses?.data.length"
     [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element" (click)="toggleRow(element)">
</tr>
```

As the `element` is added into `expandedElements` to represent it is expanded, thus you need to check whether the element is in the `expandedElements` with **`isExpanded(element)`**.

**Latest**

```
<div class="example-element-detail" *ngIf="element.addresses?.data.length" [@detailExpand]="isExpanded(element)">
  <div class="inner-table mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="isExpanded(element)">
```

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" [class.example-element-row]="element.addresses?.data.length"
     [class.example-expanded-row]="isExpanded(element)" (click)="toggleRow(element)">
</tr>
```

> .component.ts

```
export class TableExpandableRowsExample {

  ...

  expandedElements: any[] = [];

  ...

  toggleRow(element: User) {
    element.addresses && (element.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data.length 
      ? this.toggleElement(element) 
      : null;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.innerTables.forEach((table, index) => (table.dataSource as MatTableDataSource<Address>).sort = this.innerSort.toArray()[index]);
  }

  isExpanded(row: User): string {
    const index = this.expandedElements.findIndex(x => x.name == row.name);
    if (index !== -1) {
      return 'expanded';
    }
    return 'collapsed';
  }

  toggleElement(row: User){
    const index = this.expandedElements.findIndex(x => x.name == row.name);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.expandedElements.push(row);
    } else {
      this.expandedElements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-7itkv8)

Comment: Will it be possible to create a third grid inside the addresses grid ? @yong